# Múltiples filtros query MySql, no devuelve resultado esperado

Tags: mysql

tengo que mostrar todas las ordenes restringiendo de la siguiente manera:

```
1.  Ocultar órdenes con estado 'pendiente'. 
2.  Ocultar órdenes con tipo_servicio.servicio = 1 y orden.tipo <> 1 
    ( tipo_servicio = 1 y orden.tipo = 2 NO debería mostrarse || tipo_servicio = 1 y orden.tipo = 1 SI debería mostrarse || tipo_servicio = 2 y orden.tipo = 1 y 2 SI deberían mostrarse). 
3.  Ocultar órdenes con estado 'cancelada' con motivo_cancelacion in ( A, B )
4.  Ocultar órdenes con estado 'cancelada' con motivo_cancelacion C por un periodo de 31 días desde su cancelación.
```

tabla orden : id_orden, id_tipo_servicio, status, tipo, fecha_cancelacion, motivo_cancelacion

```
.id_orden = PK
.id_servicio = FK tabla tipo_servicio
.id_cliente = FK tabla cliente
.status = 'pendiente', 'asignar', 'encurso', 'fin', 'cancelada'
.tipo = 1, 2
.fecha_cancelacion =  Si se cancela la orden se almacena current_date(), si no se queda a null
.motivo_cancelacion = Si se cancela los posibles valores son : 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', null, '', cualquien otro motivo puesto por el usuario. 
                      Si no se cancela la orden queda a null.
                      Si se descancela la orden queda empty.
.deleted = 0 / 1.
```

tabla tipo_servicio : id_servicio, servicio

```
.id_servicio = PK
.servicio = 1, 2, 3, ...
```

tabla cliente : id_servicio, servicio

```
.id_cliente = PK
```

La query la dejé así:

```
select * FROM orden o 
LEFT JOIN tipo_servicio t ON o.id_servicio = t.id_servicio  
where o.deleted=0 
-- AND o.status != 'pendiente' -- Ocultar estado pendiente  
-- AND t.id_servicio != 1 and o.tipo != 1 -- Ocultar ordenes de tipo_servicio.id_servicio 1 cuando o.tipo != 1  
-- AND orden.motivo_cancelacion not in ('A', 'B') -- Ocultar estas cancelaciones con estos estados    
-- AND orden.motivo_cancelacion = 'C' and o.fecha_cancelacion BETWEEN date_add(current_date(),INTERVAL -31 DAY) AND current_date() -- Ocultar las cancelaciones 'C' que tengan más de 31 días   
AND o.id_cliente = '1'
```

Por separado los filtros funcionan, pero todos juntos no. Creo que es un asunto de paréntesis o jugar con el or. Alguien podría ayudarme? Gracias.

Comment: Analizando de a poco tus condiciones, me puedes aclarar la nº2, por favor: creo que en la definición que pones al principio, _"2.  Ocultar órdenes con tipo_servicio.servicio = 1 y orden.tipo <> 1 "_, a mi parecer difiere de la que pones en el comentario dentro de la query `Ocultar ordenes de tipo_servicio.id_servicio 1 cuando o.tipo != 1`, ya que esta última colocas una subcondición, mientras que en la definición de arriba dices que se cumplan ambas (y que de hecho así lo tienes codificado en tu `AND t.id_servicio != 1 and o.tipo != 1`).

Comment: Ah, también sería bueno si puedes mostrar ejemplo de datos en tabla `orden`, de resultado esperado y de resultado obtenido de queries, por favor.

Comment: Finalmente, en la última condición, la nº4, efectivamente te falta paréntesis, y una subcondición extra para que se cumplan la mayor cantidad posible de casos. A saber: `AND ( orden.motivo_cancelacion != 'C' OR ( orden.motivo_cancelacion = 'C' and o.fecha_cancelacion BETWEEN ... ) )`

Comment: La condición dos es mostrar solo las emergencias de luz, quiero decir:
tipo_servicio.id_servicio ( 1-luz, 2-gas ), orden.tipo (1-emergencias, 2-averias, 3....). Finalmente parece que me funcionó con subQuerys :

AND orden.id_orden not in 
( select orden.id_orden FROM orden LEFT JOIN tipo_servicio ON servicio.id_servicio = tipo_servicio.id_servicio 
 where tipo_servicio.nombre = 'Mantenimiento Servicio Luz'
 and  orden.id_tipo != 1). y así con todas.
Ahora tengo que traducirlo a yii2. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Mmm, las subqueries generalmente funcionan bien, pero son un poco pesadas para el servidor, ya que si tienes muchos registros que retornar en tu query principal, le estás diciendo al server que por cada uno de esos registros, haga esa subquery... Yo creo que puedes analizar bien cómo funciona tu subquery, y tratar de llevarla a tu query principal. Como dices, es muy probable que sea cosa de paréntesis, y de, como puse en mi sugerencia del nº4, te falte agregar una subcondición para cuando la condición principal no se cumpla.

Comment: Tienes razón la verdad, y traducirlo a yii2 con subquerys es un lio.
Tu filtro con paréntesis funciona bien, pero me oculta las ordenes que no están canceladas y no debería no? pues :
orden.motivo_cancelacion != 'Contrato dado de baja' ya debería mostrar las que no tienen motivo_cancelacion no?

Comment: En ese caso específico, tal vez tengas que agregar la subcondición de los casos `NULL`, que puede que los esté ignorando al hacer comparaciones con cadenas (que no se comparan como los valores `null`)...

Comment: Creo que soy muy malo con esto.. no consigo hacer que aparezcan el resto de estados que no sean cancelados y por otra parte tampoco soy capaz de hacer la nº2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que comentas de que por separado funcionan la respuesta es:

```
    select * FROM orden o 
LEFT JOIN tipo_servicio t ON o.id_servicio = t.id_servicio  
where o.deleted=0 AND o.id_cliente = '1' AND (
     (o.status != 'pendiente') -- Ocultar estado pendiente  
     OR (t.id_servicio != 1 and o.tipo != 1) -- Ocultar ordenes de tipo_servicio.id_servicio 1 cuando o.tipo != 1  
     OR (orden.motivo_cancelacion not in ('A', 'B')) -- Ocultar estas cancelaciones con estos estados    
     OR( orden.motivo_cancelacion = 'C' and o.fecha_cancelacion BETWEEN date_add(current_date(),INTERVAL -31 DAY) AND current_date()) -- Ocultar las cancelaciones 'C' que tengan más de 31 días   
)
```

lo que te ocurría es que si pones todos las condiciones con AND se tienen que cumplir todas. En este caso vas indicado o una u otra.
Espero que te sirva.
Saludos.

Comment: Con el cambio a OR omite el AND o.id_cliente = 1 y me trae los registros de todos los clientes. Finalmente lo hice con subquerys y parece que funciona. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Es verdad no lo tuve en cuenta lo siento, he editado la consulta y ahora si tiene en cuenta el cliente. Te lo actualizo porque hacerlo con subquerys no sería optimo si se puede hacer con una condición. Espero que te funcione

Comment: Me da error en el 1º paréntesis: inexperado '(' y no consigo ver porque, pareciera estar bien. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si me había dejado el OR lo siento, prueba ahora que ya no tiene que dar error de sintaxis

Comment: Me alegro que te funcione :), lo que te recomiendo es que no utilices subquery a la ligera si crees que existe una mejor solución por temas de rendimiento. Si tu consulta ha sido resulta indica que ha sido resuelto. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, resuelto! :) Muchas gracias!